# Running for loop on matrix data by level in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I am trying to create a loop that can detrend variables in a time series by fish ID (Column = ID). See the picture for an example of what the data set looks like. The first fish is labeled Ring10_1_2. Detrending the data requires it to be a matrix which can be quite tricky to filter. After the loop, I would like to be able put all the detrended variables along with ID into a table.

```
raw_data <- read_csv("Hatch5_Data.csv")
raw_data[ , c('Distance', 'Cu','Ca' )] <- list(NULL)
raw_data
raw_data<-as.matrix(raw_data)
is.matrix(raw_data)
raw_data

detrend_table <- tibble(ID = character(), Mg = numeric(), Mn = numeric(), Zn = numeric(), Sr = numeric(), Ba = numeric(), Pb = numeric(), All = numeric())
 
for(fish in 1:length(raw_data$ID)) {
  ID <- as.character(raw_data[[fish]][1,1])

  trend <- lm(raw_data[[fish]]~c(1:nrow(raw_data[[fish]])))
  
  detrend <- residuals(trend) #Calculate detrend 
  
  detrend_df <- as.data.frame(detrend) #turn matrix back into data.frame
  
  #need to somehow put variables Mg, Mn, Zn, Sr, Ba, Pb, and All from the detrend_df into a table #along with variable ID
  colnames(smooth_table) <- c("ID", "Mg", "Mn","Zn", "Sr", "Ba", "Pb", "All")
test_test <- cbind(ID, Mg, Mn, Zn, Sr, Ba, Pb, All)
detrend_table <- rbind(detrend_table, test_test)
rm(test_test)
}
```

[Example of raw_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imtbt.jpg)

#Example data below with 3 different fish ID's

```
ID  Group   Ca  Mg  Mn  Zn  Sr  Ba  Pb  All Distance
Ring10_1_2  Cohort5 0.969682852 0.638314503 0.027960254 0.593722927 0.9761744   0.742428173 0.995916616 2.002425858 1
Ring10_1_2  Cohort5 0.950039709 0.659839604 0.034176345 0.666816037 0.944055201 0.700760613 0.829762968 2.061592599 2
Ring10_1_2  Cohort5 0.929940955 0.672514261 0.034923667 0.651097448 0.961016021 0.807228657 0.895389017 2.165764033 3
Ring10_1_2  Cohort5 0.970645899 0.60006045  0.034644892 0.646647345 0.941311836 0.770355035 0.834910538 2.051707722 4
Ring10_1_2  Cohort5 0.959930378 0.65731745  0.011547996 0.667241767 0.947787526 0.807936415 0.913641645 2.144043629 5
Ring10_1_2  Cohort5 0.947703348 0.637225331 0.047195786 0.640126974 0.963564452 0.719497669 0.808383245 2.04404576  6
Ring10_2_2  Cohort5 0.905894462 0.637731131 0.044317438 0.623279591 0.987656828 0.700989761 0.698770512 2.006317921 7
Ring10_2_2  Cohort5 0.909404403 0.661012842 0.029021928 0.652318079 0.948393369 0.788455251 0.622843189 2.130808101 8
Ring10_2_2  Cohort5 0.953808766 0.677290226 0.021262134 0.727831164 0.883979491 0.721041123 0.57050678  2.147424647 9
Ring10_2_2  Cohort5 0.902826638 0.686773183 0.019931539 0.733368096 0.959805526 0.800682787 0.553510306 2.240755606 10
Ring10_2_2  Cohort5 0.87556279  0.704397377 0.034091674 0.750200883 1.016813511 0.874106443 0.824459437 2.362796379 11
Ring10_3_2  Cohort5 0.869842267 0.698922208 0.039157316 0.763187497 1.004078901 0.851247927 0.982818276 2.352514948 12
Ring10_3_2  Cohort5 0.927654257 0.693359463 0.031367893 0.769742534 0.965395082 0.836088506 0.634576145 2.330558396 13
Ring10_3_2  Cohort5 0.921350184 0.709563135 0.020388219 0.759170423 0.986295866 0.792533235 0.711241798 2.281655011 14
Ring10_3_2  Cohort5 0.921405246 0.660942466 0.043624637 0.721108875 0.9517926   0.803623938 0.807700407 2.229299915 15
```

Comment: Please share a subset of your data reproducibly, not as a picture. `dput(raw_data[1:5, ])` is a great way to make a copy/pasteable version of the first 5 rows of `raw_data` -- choose a small subset that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Why are you using `as.matrix`? Your data appears to have both strings and numbers, so converting numbers unnecessarily to character and then trying to do ops on them is inefficient at best.

Comment: Also, iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.